# By using the following loss function I am trying to train a model, but during the training I am getting the following error

Tags: python, keras

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np


def Active_Contour_Loss(y_true, y_pred): 

    """
    lenth term
    """

    x = y_pred[:,:,1:,:] - y_pred[:,:,:-1,:] # horizontal and vertical directions 
    y = y_pred[:,:,:,1:] - y_pred[:,:,:,:-1]

    delta_x = x[:,:,1:,:-2]**2
    delta_y = y[:,:,:-2,1:]**2
    delta_u = K.abs(delta_x + delta_y) 

    lenth = K.mean(K.sqrt(delta_u + 0.00000001)) # equ.(11) in the paper

    """
    region term
    """

    C_1 = np.ones((256, 256))
    C_2 = np.zeros((256, 256))

    region_in = K.abs(K.mean( y_pred[:,0,:,:] * ((y_true[:,0,:,:] - C_1)**2) ) ) # equ.(12) in the paper
    region_out = K.abs(K.mean( (1-y_pred[:,0,:,:]) * ((y_true[:,0,:,:] - C_2)**2) )) # equ.(12) in the paper

    lambdaP = 1 # lambda parameter could be various.
    mu = 1 # mu parameter could be various.
    
    return lenth + lambdaP * (mu * region_in + region_out)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
107/112 [===========================>..] - ETA: 3s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.9701
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: is there any problem with my answer, it's something not clear? you think that's something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this post lack the info to give a complete answer, i can only give a series of advice to solve the problem:

1. loss at `nan` means that with at least one of the inputs the network fails to compute the loss value ( this happens because the number that keras shows at `loss: nan` it's the mean of all losses ), to investigate this better observe the training and watch if it's always `nan`or it becomes `nan` after a specific sample.
2. the loss at `nan` means that you loss function is not working, to undestand what part is not working well simplify your loss ( so instead of returning `lenth + lambdaP * (mu * region_in + region_out)` try returning only `lenth` and see if the output it's again nan ( if it is the problem is on the `lenth` computation)) with this method you can narrow down on what part of the code is not working